# Microsoft Office 2019 Installation - Any way to scan product keys from COA stickers?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, automation, product-key, barcode-scanner

I have approximately 450 ASUS Chromebooks running Windows 10 that need to have Microsoft Office 2019 installed.  I have individual product key stickers for each computer to register Microsoft Office 2019.   When I look at the COA sticker, there are two barcodes.

[Microsoft Office 2019 COA Sticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NwOR.png)

The top barcode corresponds to the value W2F-00188 and the other barcode corresponds to the value 04053000035198.  Obviously, this is not the product key for Office 2019.   Is there some way for me to translate either number into a scannable value for the product key for Office 2019?   Is there some way to automate this process of entering a barcode for each laptop or does Microsoft expect end users to enter the full product key manually?   I would like to think that in 2021 there would be some way to not have to enter in 450 individual product keys manually on each unit, but I figured I should ask here before assuming.

Comment: Microsoft does not expect somebody to purchase 450 individual licenses for Office.  That typically is handled through a volume license and activated by communicating with a KMS.  I am going to guess that barcode isn't unique.  There are tools to remotely manage 450 machines, but even then, you would still have to enter those product keys somewhere.

Comment: I did not purchase the keys, they were provided by a 3rd party that is requesting that we register Office 2019 on each machine.

Comment: I know of no way to deploy 450 retail licenses.  Any deployment tools are all designed are volume license keys

Comment: I aggree with Ramhound, the batch activation method is applicable to the volume licensed version of Office. To activate the retail version of Office, we need the manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-WindowsKey {
    ## function to retrieve the Windows Product Key from any PC
    param ($targets = "$env:COMPUTERNAME")
    $hklm = 2147483650
    $regPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    $regValue = "DigitalProductId"
    Foreach ($target in $targets) {
        $productKey = $null
        $win32os = $null
        $wmi = [WMIClass]"\\$target\root\default:stdRegProv"
        $data = $wmi.GetBinaryValue($hklm,$regPath,$regValue)
        $binArray = ($data.uValue)[52..66]
        $charsArray = "B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","­R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
        ## decrypt base24 encoded binary data
        For ($i = 24; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
            $k = 0
            For ($j = 14; $j -ge 0; $j--) {
                $k = $k * 256 -bxor $binArray[$j]
                $binArray[$j] = [math]::truncate($k / 24)
                $k = $k % 24
            }
            $productKey = $charsArray[$k] + $productKey
            If (($i % 5 -eq 0) -and ($i -ne 0)) {
                $productKey = "-" + $productKey
            }
        }
        $win32os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $target
        $obj = New-Object Object
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Caption -value $win32os.Caption
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty CSDVersion -value $win32os.CSDVersion
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSArch -value $win32os.OSArchitecture
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty BuildNumber -value $win32os.BuildNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty RegisteredTo -value $win32os.RegisteredUser
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductID -value $win32os.SerialNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $productkey
        $obj
    }
}
```